# check that two string are identical VB net.

Tags: vb.net

Hello, I want to make a comparison between two Strings, the first is in the given base and do the other is retrieved from `TextBox`, but the result is always `do`,

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Bcon_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bcon.Click

        Dim cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=BANIX;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from utilisateurs", cnn)
        Dim rd As SqlDataReader

        Dim sr As String = vbNullString

        Try
            cnn.Open()
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While rd.Read
                sr = rd.GetString(1)
                RTB.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "DB login = " & sr)
                RTB.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "TBLogin = " & TBlogin.Text)
                RTB.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "IsMatch sr:" & Regex.IsMatch(TBlogin.Text, sr))
                RTB.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Equals sr : " & String.Equals(TBlogin.Text, sr))

                If (TBlogin.Text = sr) Then
                    RTB.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Identique")
                Else
                    RTB.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "n'est pas Identique")
                End If
            End While
            rd.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            RTB.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & " cannot connect !")
        End Try

        cnn.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please make sure that your posts are in english, thank you. Can you also provide any errors (if any) you are receiving, what you've tried, etc, etc....

Comment: `the result is always do`, what does that mean?

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand this "... but the result is always **`do`**". Anyway, can you show the output of `RTB`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to clearly know what you mean by `identical`, e.g. references to the same string in memory or bit-wise equivalence, equals case insensitive...

To check that two strings are equal you have used one of the ways in your sample [string.equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325.aspx)

Another way is `String.Compare(str1,str2)`, it returns a integer value, when the two strings are equivalent then this value will be 0. When `str1` is less than `str2` the value will be less than zero and when `str1` is greater than `str2` the value will be greater than zero. This method has different overloads which allow you to control the way that the strings are compared, depending on what you consider equivalent. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) has usage examples.

Case Insensitive example below outputs "Are Equal" to the console

```
  Dim str1 As String = "TestString" 
  Dim str2 As String = "teststring" 
  If String.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0 Then
      Console.WriteLine("Are Equal")
  Else
      Console.WriteLine("Are Not Equal") 
  End If
```

Comment: i already used this method but it didn't work , i found the problem in the declaration of data in the sql server
thank you for your help